# Requiring multiple authentication schemes with Owin and WebApi and accessing the target class

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin, middleware

We have a need to protect our WebApi services with 2 separate authentication schemes, but we need both to be required.

Here's the scenario:

We have an internal service registry where service consumers will register for an API Key and shared secret.  These are then used in a standard pattern for generating a HMAC that should be sent with every web service call.  These API Keys essentially represent software system.

However, at an application level, we also want to authenticate our users individually.  We're using an OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider to connect to LDAP to authenticate the user, pull some roles from our app internally, and then generate/return the Bearer token.

I initially tried creating a custom AuthenticationHandler Owin middleware to implement the HMAC scheme, but this wasn't working how I wanted.  In that scenario, if either the HMAC or OAuth authenticated, the user was granted access.

What I've done in the interim is changed the HMAC logic as a more generic OwinMiddleware.  Here's a general idea of what I'm doing:

```
public class HMACMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    private HMACOptions _HMACOptions;

    public HMACMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next, IAppBuilder app, HMACOptions options) : base(next)
    {
        _HMACOptions = options;
    }

    public override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        // Pull headers use for HMAC generation, process them and handle any errors

        // Authenticate with the external service registry
        string authFailureReason;
        var authenticated = _HMACOptions.AuthStrategy.DoAuthentication(requestData, out authFailureReason);

        if(authenticated)
        {
            return Next.Invoke(context);
        } 
        else 
        {
            context.response.StatusCode = 401;
            contextresponse.ReasonPhrase = "An error occurred authenticating via HMAC";

            return context.response.WriteAsync(authFailureReason);
        }
    }
}
```

If HMAC auth fails, I short circuit the Owin pipeline and return immediately.

There are a couple things I don't like about this implementation in its current form:

- This applies to every Owin request.  What I really want it to apply to is every WebAPI route instead.  That way we can supply WebApi help pages that don't need to be authenticated against
- Is this really the correct way to handle this?  It feels like it should be an AuthenticationHandler, but I could not figure out how to make it required, even if another authentication scheme authenticated

---

**A side question**:  We have a version of this for WebApi as a DelegatingHandler.  That version can access the target method (IE:  if the route comes in as /api/users/1, we can access the GET method of the UsersController) by using the controllerSelector and actionSelector from webApi's GlobalConfiguration.  We can then check that method for custom attributes that may affect the call we make to the HMAC Authenticator.  Is there anyway to do something similar in Owin?

Comment: How about adding ClaimsIdentity for both authentication schema then check those in the authorization filter or in the api level?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm facing a similar scenario and would be interested in knowing what approach you chose.